# node.js multiple app without multiple server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**I want my app to be example.com but the dashboard to be dashboard.example.com**, how do I do that with one server running? I can easily spin up 2 express app and connect to the same db, and configure ngix config but I feel that is not a proper way to do things.

Any clue? I'm using express.js anyway.

Comment: Did you ever heard of [subdomains](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain)

Comment: @Bálint how to configure it? I can do that with 2 webserver

Answer (score 0):

You can try [express-sudomain](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-subdomain)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var router = express.Router();

//api specific routes
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.send('Welcome to our API!');
});

router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    res.json([
        { name: "Brian" }
    ]);
});

app.use(subdomain('dashboard', router));
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: this is easy to setup 1 webserver